# UI5 Component Concept issue

Tags: components, sapui5

I'm trying to use the component concept for UI5 and have just built the below:

Index.html snippet:

```
<script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
                data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
                "sap.ui.ui5test.myapp": "./"
            }'>
        </script>
        <!-- only load the mobile lib "sap.m" and the "sap_bluecrystal" theme -->

        <script>
        new sap.m.Shell({
            app : new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                name : "sap.ui.ui5test.myapp"
            })
        }).placeAt("content");

        </script>
```

Component.js snippet:

```
jQuery.sap.declare("sap.ui.ui5test.myapp.Component");

sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("sap.ui.ui5test.myapp.Component", {

        createContent : function() {
            var oView = new sap.ui.core.mvc.View({
                id : "testview",
                name : "sap.ui.ui5test.myapp.views.FirstView",
                type : "JS",
                viewData : {component : this}
            });

            var jsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            jsonModel.loadData('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Auckland');
            //jsonModel.loadData('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=524901,703448,2643743&units=metric');
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(jsonModel);

            oView.setModel(jsonModel);


        }

});
```

In the above snippet for component.js, if I return the view as return oView; it is giving me an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". It goes away as soon as I remove the return statement.

If I dont return the view will it navigate to the view I instantiated and loaded above? As I see in the chrome developer tools, I do not seem to find the js file for FirstView to open it as I think it is not getting loaded.

Please suggest how to correct this and how to navigate further.

Awaiting your prompt responses eagerly.

Cheers,
AW

Comment: Please also show me the FirstView.js

Comment: createContent : function(oController) {
  
  // to avoid scroll bars on desktop the root view must be set to block display
  this.setDisplayBlock(true);
  
  this.app = new sap.m.SplitApp();
  var masterView = new sap.ui.core.mvc.XMLView({
   id : "master", // sap.ui.core.ID   
   viewName : "sap.ui.ui5test.myapp.views.Master", // string      
  });
  
  this.app.addPage(masterView, true);
  return app;
  
  
  /*return new sap.m.Page({
   title: "Title",
   content: [
   
   ]
  });*/
 } Snippet for FirstView.js

Answer (score 1):

1. I checked your FirstView.js. Please do the following in your return statement:

   `return this.app;`

   As there is no local variable called app, if you write **return app**, then app is undefined.
2. Please use sap.ui.view in your createContent method:

   ```
        var oView = new sap.ui.view({
           id : "testview",
           viewName : "sap.ui.ui5test.myapp.views.FirstView",
           type : "JS",
           viewData : {component : this}
       });
   ```

Comment: Hello Allen, it is not even going to the firstview as in the first view I've placed the split app but it just shows me a plain screen with the bluecrystal theme but not the blank splitapp structure. I'm placing the return statement in the component.js file as the root view. So as soon as I place return oView in component.js it is throwing error. It is not shown in the code snippet given above as I'm was trying to test it but mentioned it in the comments. I think I should return the root view from the component.js but not able to place the return statement and gets the error mentioned above.

Comment: Hi Allen, for some reasons I was not able to find the sap.ui.view and that is what I was looking for. But again I searched and now I'm able to find it. Thanks to you. Though now it gives me this error as soon as I do it. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined". Please suggest.